# Date Overlaps in Hibernate Restrictions

Tags: hibernate, date, overlap, restrictions

In SQL, we can check the date overlaps as

```
SELECT (DATE '2001-02-16', DATE '2001-12-21') OVERLAPS
   (DATE '2001-10-30', DATE '2002-10-30');
```

How can we imitate the same using hibernate `Restrictions` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", startDate2));
 criteria.add(Restrictions.le("startDate", endDate2));
```

Where:

`startDate` and `endDate` are your entity's dates.